# converting LINQ group by result straight into model

Tags: c#, linq

I want to store the result of my LINQ query straight into my model but I can only get it working by first storing it into a variable.

```
var mdl = (from age in dy.vwFacetPool
                       group age by new { age.AgeGroup, age.AgeString }
                      into grp
                       select new { a = grp.Key.AgeGroup, b = grp.Key.AgeString, c = grp.Count() }).ToList();
```

but I want to store it into a model rather than a variable at first go.

I have the model

```
  public class AgeGroupCounts
{
    public int AgeGroup { get; set; }
    public string AgeValue { get; set; }
    public int AgeCount { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
public class NewEmail
{
    public NewEmail()
    {
        this.Newz = new News();
        //this.Age = new AgeGroupCounts();
        this.AgeGroup = new List<AgeGroupCounts>();
    }

    public News Newz { get; set; }
    //public AgeGroupCounts Age { get; set; }
    public List<AgeGroupCounts> AgeGroup { get; set; }
}
```

so then i want to map the 3 output fields from the select to the model fields but am lost at this point

```
 model.AgeGroup = (from age in dy.vwFacetPool
                       group age by new { age.AgeGroup, age.AgeString }
                      into grp
                       select new { grp.Key.AgeGroup, grp.Key.AgeString, grp.Count() }).ToList();
```

I know i can store it into a var and the the model but that seems like i am doing something the wrong way!

Comment: Change the select statement to: select new AgeGroupCounts { AgeGroup = grp.Key.AgeGroup, AgeValue = grp.Key.AgeString, AgeCount = grp.Count() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select an `AgeGroupCounts` instead of an anonymous type you will get back a `List<AgeGroupCounts>` from the LINQ query:

```
model.AgeGroup = (from age in dy.vwFacetPool
                   group age by new { age.AgeGroup, age.AgeString }
                  into grp
                   select new AgeGroupCounts { AgeGroup = grp.Key.AgeGroup, AgeValue = grp.Key.AgeString, AgeCount = grp.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the novice question

Answer (score 0):

I think your select statement shouldn't be an anonymous type...

```
 select new { grp.Key.AgeGroup, grp.Key.AgeString, grp.Count()...
```

try and change it to

```
 select new AgeGroupCounts() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var mdl = (from age in dy.vwFacetPool
    group age by new { age.AgeGroup, age.AgeString }
    into grp
    select new AgeGroupCounts {
        AgeGroup = grp.Key.AgeGroup, 
        AgeValue = grp.Key.AgeString, 
        AgeCount = grp.Count()
    }).ToList();
```